# How did the policeman survive?

Tags: plot-explanation, charmed

In ***Charmed*** and in an episode (though I can't remember which one), (my sister and mum made me watch it), there was this one scene where a **demon** was walking down a street and causing chaos in the process.

While he was walking down the road, a police car came speeding around the corner and up toward him but not at him, the demon threw an energy ball at the car's bonnet and the car erupted into a massive ball of flames.

Now here is the disturbing part:

**The policeman driving gets out of the burned out car unscathed and runs away as if nothing happened**.

***HOW?***

Comment: Was the whole car in flames or just the hood?

Comment: The whole car was in flames after the fireball.

Comment: Are you asking how the effect was done or why he wasn't incinerated for plot purposes? It is quite common for tv producers not to want to show people dying in fireballs in these types of show. See the A-Team.

Comment: @Paulie_D But would you explain how someone would ***manage*** to survive something like that? I need an answer, not something in comments guys.

Comment: It's a **TV show**...with **demons**....it's not reality. Again are you asking about the stunt work or how this could happen magically? The first is a proper question, the second it just something that happens in TV...all the time.

Comment: @Paulie_D You are obviously not getting the point. I do know the whole thing is in ***seasons*** and not a **TV show**, and I know it isn't reality, don't tell me something I didn't know. All I was asking was for an answer to how this could have been done with the whole car exploding which should have killed the policeman but it didn't, I want an answer, not some sort of rejecting comment. I am asking how it could have been done but obviously not magically. Read the question next time and actually try to answer it.

Comment: So it is a stunt work question... right?

Comment: @Paulie_D It is a question asking how it was possible for someone to get out of an exploded car unharmed and managed to run away, if you wish to answer it as a stunt question, be my guest I don't care, but I do want an answer just like everyone else does with their own questions.